# Android App Class Not Found Error

Tags: android

I developed an Android project in the package:`com.anand.eprint`.

The package contains `ePrintActivity.java` and `GmailSender.java`. The `ePrintActivity` calls `GmailSender` internally. This is working successfully.

I exported the project, taken backup and formated the system. 
Now I installed new OS, eclipse and android environment.

Imported the same Android project into eclipse.

Now I am trying to install and run in `Emulators/Android` Phones.

I am getting error: `ClassNotFoundError:GmailSender`.

Please anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

- Right click on project > Android Tools > Fix Project properties
- Project > Clean

Answer (score 0):

That or you need to add the declaration of the activity in the manifest.

```
      <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ePrinterActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
          <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GmailSender" >
        <intent-filter >
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Take out .GmailSender if its not an activity.